# What is difference between str(77) and int(77) in python

Tags: python, variables

I am new in Python, going through basics and working on concatenating of two strings. I am fine with string concatenation and also if I want to add any integer to the string, I first have to change its type from integer to string using str() function. My doubt is how this will affect in the memory and memory address.

example

```
new="This is my"+str(2)+"program"
print(new)
print(id(str(2)))
print(id(int(2)))
```

output is

```
This is my2program
4429764648
140698267462832
```

Process finished with exit code 0

How it is changing in memory from int(2) to str(2), are both same or can 77 be a string?

Comment: `str(2)` returns the integer as a string, `int(2)` return the integer as an integer. As you can see, `int(2)` doesn't make much sense. The reverse operation is `int("2")`, which returns the string as an integer. printing out the `type()` may help you understand what is going on. (i.e. `print(type(int(2)), type(str(2)))`)

Comment: You can't actually change the type of something – `str(2)` creates a new string object that is the textual representation of the number two.

Comment: thanks :) got it now

Comment: Just fyi, if you want to add an integer to a string, you can also use (in python 3.6 and up) `a = 2` and `new=f"This is my {a} program"`

Answer (score 0):

```
new="This is my"+str(2)+"program"
print(new)

for _ in range(3):
    print(id(str(2)))
    print(id(int(2)))
    print(id((2)))
    print('-------------------')
```

This is my2program
2639932006728
1469953120
1469953120

---

2639932006728
1469953120
1469953120

---

2639932006728
1469953120
1469953120

---

Answer (score 0):

77 could be a str if you take it in " " .  And if you add an int with a str you will have an error